# How to hide various Android logs in VS Code when working with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I just want to hide the `W/` logs cropping up in the console. I just want to make room for my own debugging logs.

[image]

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for an answer to this:

The Debug Console in VS Code starting from version 1.49 supports filtering, making it easier for users to find the output they are looking for, or to hide irrelevant logging output.

The filter also supports exclude patterns (for example, patterns starting with an exclamation mark) which should be prefixed with `!`.

To filter the Debug Console in VS Code, you can use the filter text field in the Debug Console.

**So if you want to hide logs containing the word W/, you can type `!W/` in the filter text field.**

**But If you want to hide logs with multiple patterns you can separate them with a comma `,`. For example, if you want to hide all logs that contain W/ , E/ and D/ you can do something like this `!W/, !D/, !E/`.**
[Explaination Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrPd2.gif)

See [vs code version 1.49 changelog](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_49.md#debug-console-filter) for more info.

I hope this helps!